# How to view in slow motion on Apple TV 4K

Tags: appletv

Is there some way to switch to slow motion (slo-mo) while watching the Apple TV 4K?

I have the second generation Siri Remote with Siri button placed on the side edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature isn't available on Apple TV yet.

I would recommend suggesting this as a feature for the later versions of tvOS at [Apple Product Feedback - Apple TV](https://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-tv/).

Answer (score 0):

Press Pause / Play and then press Left or Right to go forwards or backwards in slow motion.